# Example of programming language that is left associative?

Tags: operators, programming-languages

I was teaching a friend about programming and I had a hard time convincing them that `a = b` and `b = a` are two very different things.

I eventually found the correct words to describe it ([right associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Right-associativity_of_assignment_operators)) which got me thinking.

Are there any programming languages which are left associative? I have never seen a language where:

`a = b` results in b being set to the value of a.

Comment: I guess that your question is misleading. You ask about assignment associativity but market your question as language associativity, whatever that means (I believe it means nothing.)

Comment: @LittleAlien how would you clarify the question? From what I have seen all operators in each language are set to right associative. I thought there might be a language that was written to be left associative.

Comment: It is not difficult to find out that there are operations which are not right associative. Even under the link that you posted, we read about non-associative operators and see a link to C-language op precedence table with associativity. You will find left and right associative operators there. You will not find any "right associative language" in Google. You have just [picked a single operator and extended its associativity to all operators](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7MTM4BKZ_E). Because there are no RA-languages, it made me to think that you ask about LA assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talk about `Operator associativity` we should actually consider two types of `associativity`: `side_associative` (e.g. `=` ) or `non-associative` (e.g. `==` ) as it doesn't make any difference for a machine if it get's the line from left to right or from right to left.

There are no such programming languages that are originally `left associative` but some of them allow it via operator overloading and some (e.g. `R`) will allow both: `->` and `<-`.

I believe no-one will like it in Europe but it might be found lovely in the Middle East. I can imagine that there are `IDE`s that switch right-side with left-side but at the end compilers are written in an European way.

Comment: "Non-associative" does definitely not mean that it does not matter whether it's read from right or left. Depending on context it can either mean that the operator does not have the associative property (i.e. `(a op b) op c` is not equivalent to `a op (b op c)`) (as used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Non-associativity)) or that it's neither left- nor right-associative (i.e. multiple uses of the operator always have to be parenthesized) - as used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity#Non-associative_operators).

Answer (score 5):

You misunderstood associativity. An operator `op` is associative if `(a op b) op c` is equivalent to `a op (b op c)`. For operators that are not associative it thus becomes relevant whether `a op b op c` stands for the former or the latter. Thus we distinguish between left-associative operators, where it's `(a op b) op c`, and right-associative operators, where it's `a op (b op c)`.

Most operators in most languages are left-associative. Take for example `-`: `a - b - c` is equivalent to `(a - b) - c` in most languages, not `a - (b - c)`.

The assignment operator is an exception from that as `(a = b) = c` is generally not legal (as you can't assign to the result of an assignment). Thus in most languages `a = b = c` is equivalent to `a = (b = c)`. A notable exception is Python where `a = b = c` does not associate at all and is simply illegal.

None of this has anything to do with the difference between `a = b` and `b = a`. Since this involves only a single use of the `=` operator, associativity does not factor into this at all. Rather the relevant property is [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property): An operator `op` is commutative if `a op b` is equivalent to `b op a`. I'm not aware of any language where assignment is commutative, nor do I have an idea of how it could be.

Concepts like left-commutativity or right-commutativity do not exist. There is, to the best of my knowledge, no term for the question "Does `a = b` assign `b` to `a` or vice-versa?" - that's just part of the semantics of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so. Though you can always overload the assignment operator and cause complete confusion inside your c++.

Answer (score 1):

R has both `<-` and `->` assignment operators defined.

```
> b <- 42
> b -> a
> a
[1] 42
```